# replace character if it appears only at beginning of string using re.sub in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want only second `p` to be replaced by `k`.

```
string="paper"
d=re.sub('[^p]p','k',string)
print d
```

This is giving me return `pker`.

I don't know why `a` is also being replaced.

Comment: Is there a more general problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a negative look behind and specify only a single replace to occur:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'paper'
>>> re.sub('(?<!^)p', 'k', s, 1)
'paker'
```

But then you could do that without a regex as such:

```
s[0] + s[1:].replace('p', 'k', 1)
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me that there's a third parameter for replace :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using capturing groups and back references to capture all that's *before* the second `p` and all that's *after* the second `p`:

```
re.sub(r'(.+)p(.+)', r'\1k\2', string)
=> 'paker'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been messing around trying to get this to work for the first letter of any word - without having the specify it:

```
re.sub(r'(\w)(?=\w*\1\b)', 'k', s[::-1])[::-1]
```

It needs a variable length lookbehind which is not supported by Python, so to get past this I reverse the string, use a variable length lookahead and then reverse the result:

```
>>> s = 'paper';
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)(?=\w*\1\b)', 'k', s[::-1])[::-1]
'paker'
```

And for a sentence it uses the first letter of each word:

```
>>> s = 'arabia bababooie paper';
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)(?=\w*\1\b)', 'k', s[::-1])[::-1]
'arkbik bakakooie paker'
```